# Cannot create AWS Cognito Identity Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create a stack that will create a User Pool with its App Client and Identity Pool. Here's the stack:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
 
    "Parameters" : {
        "CognitoUserPoolName": {
            "Description": "Name of the Cognito user pool as a parameter passed into this template.",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },

    "Resources": {
        "UserPool": {
            "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPool",
            "Properties": {
                "UserPoolName" : {
                    "Ref": "CognitoUserPoolName"
                },
                "Policies": {
                    "PasswordPolicy": {
                        "MinimumLength": 8,
                        "RequireUppercase": true,
                        "RequireLowercase": true,
                        "RequireNumbers": true,
                        "RequireSymbols": true
                    }
                },
                "Schema": [
                    {
                        "Name": "name",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "email",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "Mutable": false,
                        "Required": true
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "phone_number",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "Mutable": false,
                        "Required": false
                    }
                ],
                "LambdaConfig": {},
                "AutoVerifiedAttributes": [
                    "email"
                ],
                "UsernameAttributes": [
                    "email"
                ],
                "SmsVerificationMessage": "Your verification code is {####}. ",
                "EmailVerificationMessage": "Your app verification code is {####}. ",
                "EmailVerificationSubject": "Your app verification code",
                "SmsAuthenticationMessage": "Your authentication code is {####}. ",
                "MfaConfiguration": "OFF",
                "EmailConfiguration": {},
                "UserPoolTags": {},
                "AdminCreateUserConfig": {
                    "AllowAdminCreateUserOnly": false,
                    "UnusedAccountValidityDays": 7,
                    "InviteMessageTemplate": {
                        "SMSMessage": "Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}. ",
                        "EmailMessage": "Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}. ",
                        "EmailSubject": "Your temporary password"
                    }
                }         
            }
        },
        "UserPoolClient": {
            "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient",
            "Description": "App Client.",
            "DependsOn": "UserPool",
            "Properties": {
                "ClientName": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${CognitoUserPoolName}Client"
                },
                "ExplicitAuthFlows": [
                    "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH"
                ],
                "GenerateSecret": false,
                "RefreshTokenValidity": 30,
                "UserPoolId": {
                    "Ref": "UserPool"
                }
            }
        },
        "IdentityPool": {
            "Type" : "AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool",
            "DependsOn": ["UserPool", "UserPoolClient"],
            "Properties" : {
                "AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities" : false,
                "CognitoIdentityProviders" : [
                    {
                        "ClientId": {
                            "Ref": "UserPool"
                        },
                        "ProviderName": {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "UserPool",
                                "Arn"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "IdentityPoolName" : {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${CognitoUserPoolName}IdentityPool"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "UserPoolARN": {
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "UserPool",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I keep getting this error:

```sh
dentityPool CREATE_FAILED   1 validation error detected: Value 'us-east-1_<>' at 'cognitoIdentityProviders.1.member.clientId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w_]+ (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: <>)
```

It looks like the format of the `User Pool ID` is incorrect.

I've tried to edit the `CognitoIdentityProviders` like this:

```
"CognitoIdentityProviders" : [
                    {
                        "ClientId": {
                            "Ref": "UserPool"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "ClientId": {
                            "Ref": "UserPoolClient"
                        }
                    }
                ],
```

But I keep getting the same error. I've used the console to create an Identity Pool before, you're supposed to add both `User Pool ID` and `App Client ID`, and the `User Pool ID` has the format `us-east-1-1_string`.

> Update 18 Jun

Following jens' answer below, I was able to create the Identity pool. However, both the `User Pool ID` and the `App client id` have the value of the `User Pool ID`: `us-east-1-1_string`.

I've tried to add another provider like this:

```
"ClientId": {
    "Ref": "UserPoolClient"
},
"ProviderName": {
    "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "UserPool",
        "ProviderName"
    ]
}
```

and it did create the right providers:

- `User Pool ID`: `us-east-1-1_string`. ex: us-east-1_Ab129faBb
- `App client id`: `string`. ex: 7lhlkkfbfb4q5kpp90urffao

  but there is a duplicate of the providers.
  I've tried to
- change the `App client id`, Provider name to `UserPoolClient` but it failed to create.
- remove the `ProviderName` of the `App client id` but it failed to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @jens' answer above. It did work, although it has an issue with the `App client id` mentioned above in my update, it did help me figure out the right template.

I've figured out the right way to write the template:

```
"CognitoIdentityProviders": [
    {
        "ClientId": {
            "Ref": "UserPoolClient"
        },
        "ProviderName": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "UserPool",
                "ProviderName"
            ]
        }
    }
],
```

That way, the stack creates the `Identity Pool` correctly.
[The AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-identitypool-cognitoidentityprovider.html) is confusing:

> ProviderName
>   The provider name for an Amazon Cognito user pool. For example, cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-2_123456789.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a bug in the CloudFormation implementation.

If you change the ClientID from `us-east-1-1_string` to `us_east_1_1_string` the template gets built, and the UI shows the correct original string (with dashes).

Since CloudFormation also has no replace-function, the only way to replace a string is by splitting and re-joining the string parts.

So for 3 dashes, you would need the following construct:

```
"ClientId": {
  "Fn::Join": ["_",
    [{"Fn::Select": ["0",{"Fn::Split": ["-",{ "Ref": "UserPool"}]}]},
    {"Fn::Select": ["1",{"Fn::Split": ["-",{ "Ref": "UserPool"}]}]},
    {"Fn::Select": ["2",{"Fn::Split": ["-",{ "Ref": "UserPool"}]}]},
    {"Fn::Select": ["3",{"Fn::Split": ["-",{ "Ref": "UserPool"}]}]}
    ] 
  ]
}
```

I tried executing your template and it always generated a string with 2 dashes for me. So for the two dashes version, this would be the complete template:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

    "Parameters": {
        "CognitoUserPoolName": {
            "Description": "Name of the Cognito user pool as a parameter passed into this template.",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },

    "Resources": {
        "UserPool": {
            "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPool",
            "Properties": {
                "UserPoolName": {
                    "Ref": "CognitoUserPoolName"
                },
                "Policies": {
                    "PasswordPolicy": {
                        "MinimumLength": 8,
                        "RequireUppercase": true,
                        "RequireLowercase": true,
                        "RequireNumbers": true,
                        "RequireSymbols": true
                    }
                },
                "Schema": [{
                        "Name": "name",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "email",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "Mutable": false,
                        "Required": true
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "phone_number",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "Mutable": false,
                        "Required": false
                    }
                ],
                "LambdaConfig": {},
                "AutoVerifiedAttributes": [
                    "email"
                ],
                "UsernameAttributes": [
                    "email"
                ],
                "SmsVerificationMessage": "Your verification code is {####}. ",
                "EmailVerificationMessage": "Your app verification code is {####}. ",
                "EmailVerificationSubject": "Your app verification code",
                "SmsAuthenticationMessage": "Your authentication code is {####}. ",
                "MfaConfiguration": "OFF",
                "EmailConfiguration": {},
                "UserPoolTags": {},
                "AdminCreateUserConfig": {
                    "AllowAdminCreateUserOnly": false,
                    "UnusedAccountValidityDays": 7,
                    "InviteMessageTemplate": {
                        "SMSMessage": "Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}. ",
                        "EmailMessage": "Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}. ",
                        "EmailSubject": "Your temporary password"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "UserPoolClient": {
            "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient",
            "Description": "App Client.",
            "DependsOn": "UserPool",
            "Properties": {
                "ClientName": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${CognitoUserPoolName}Client"
                },
                "ExplicitAuthFlows": [
                    "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH"
                ],
                "GenerateSecret": false,
                "RefreshTokenValidity": 30,
                "UserPoolId": {
                    "Ref": "UserPool"
                }
            }
        },
        "IdentityPool": {
            "Type": "AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool",
            "DependsOn": ["UserPool", "UserPoolClient"],
            "Properties": {
                "AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities": false,
                "CognitoIdentityProviders": [{
                    "ClientId": {
                      "Fn::Join": [
                        "_",
                        [
                            {
                                "Fn::Select": [
                                    "0",
                                    {
                                        "Fn::Split": [
                                            "-",
                                            {
                                                "Ref": "UserPool"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "Fn::Select": [
                                    "1",
                                    {
                                        "Fn::Split": [
                                            "-",
                                            {
                                                "Ref": "UserPool"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "Fn::Select": [
                                    "2",
                                    {
                                        "Fn::Split": [
                                            "-",
                                            {
                                                "Ref": "UserPool"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                    },
                    "ProviderName": {
                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                            "UserPool",
                            "ProviderName"
                        ]
                    }
                }],
                "IdentityPoolName": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${CognitoUserPoolName}IdentityPool"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "UserPoolARN": {
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "UserPool",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jens. It's so weird that in their docs, they don't mention that at all and why it should be: ```"ProviderName": {
                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                            "UserPool",
                            "ProviderName"
                        ]
                    }```

Comment: Actually, your answer is almost there. I'll update my question